# D3.js Right click opens popup but does not affect the source svg when pop up closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

Here is my d3.js code , from here on `right click` i am calling the function `contextmenu`

```
// Display the tiles for each bucket.
var tile = svg.selectAll(".tile")
    .data(buckets)
    .enter().append("g");

// add rect and rect attributes         
tile.append("rect")
//.enter().append("rect")
.attr("class", "tile")
.attr("x", function (d) {
return x(d.country) + margin.left + margin.left_padding;
})
.attr("y", function (d) {
return y(d.distrinct_port_nme);
})
.attr("width", x.rangeBand())
.attr("height", y.rangeBand())
.attr("stroke", "goldenrod")
.attr("fill", function (d) {
return z(d.sum_teu);
})
.on("contextmenu",contextmenu);
```

Here is my `contextmenu` function :

```
function contextmenu(){
 var node= d3.select(this);
 var position = d3.mouse(this);
d3.select('#my_custom_menu')
  .style('position', 'absolute')
  .style('left', position[0] + "px")
  .style('top', position[1] + "px")
  .style('display', 'block');

d3.event.preventDefault();
document.getElementById('nodeId').value= node
}
```

Which opens a pop up with `id= my_custom_menu` , here is the `popup` design :

```
<div id="my_custom_menu" style="display:none;">
<ul> 
<input type="hidden" name="nodeId" id="nodeId" value="" />
 <li onclick="closepop()" style="cursor:pointer;">Close</li>
 <li style="cursor:pointer;">Change color</li>
</ul>
</div
```

Clicking on the `close` it closes(hides) the `popup` :

```
function closepop(){
d3.select('#my_custom_menu')
 .style('display', 'none');
var selectNode =  document.getElementById('nodeId').value;
selectNode.style("fill", "green");
}
```

Now on `close` i tried to set the rectangle from where i right clicked `fill green`. I tried ti store the `instance` of the `right clicked rectangle` and the while closing tried to `fill` with `green` against the rectangle. But not working. Can anybody help me with my mistakes. Thanks in advance

Comment: In colseup function, which value you are getting in selectNode.? whether the respecting rect node or empty..?

Comment: I am getting the object of that rect node , if i do `alert` `selectNode` it is showing `[object SVGRectElement]`

Comment: check in console.log,if you get the rect DOM then give .style.fill="green"; check my post.

Comment: See your code works fine in `jsfiddle` , as you are taking the object of circle by `getElementById` and applying `style.fill` correspondent to that `circle` `object`. But in my code i am storing the `object` of rect in another `input type hidden field` and then applying `style.fill` on that object from taking the value from `input type`, so it is not working. Whatever I am doing by `style.fill` it is applying on that `input type hidden field`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/84Utx/4/ ...hidden field we are getting the string only not a respective object.check in console

Comment: I give one solution for your problem,make node as the global variable,then every time right we can set as current object,then you access that variable to popup function.that's it..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/w2gHw/ see the link,is it solve your problem..?

Comment: Manoj your code helped me a lot , finally i got the idea from your code. I set `dynamic id` for all the `rect element` and `pass` the `id` while calling the `function closepop` and then applied `style.fill` for respective ids.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44003/discussion-between-manoj-and-dibyendu-dutta)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I set the id correspondent to each element by :

```
.attr("id", function(d) { return "id_" + parseInt(d.x)+"_"+parseInt(d.y)+"_"+Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1) })
```

Then in the `function` `contextmenu` I get the id by :

```
function contextmenu() {
var position = d3.mouse(this);
var node= d3.select(this).attr("id");   
d3.select('#my_custom_menu')
  .style('position', 'absolute')
  .style('left', position[0]+200 + "px")
  .style('top', position[1] + "px")
  .style('display', 'block');

d3.event.preventDefault();
document.getElementById('nodeId').value= node
```

}

Then in the `function` `closepop`

```
function closepop(){
 d3.select('#my_custom_menu')
 .style('display', 'none');
 var selectN=document.getElementById('nodeId').value;
d3.select('#'+selectN)
.style('fill', 'green');
```

}

Answer (score 3):

In close up function `selectNode` fetch only the `string`. Can't call style method ,

Try this code:

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/84Utx/3/):**

```
var selectNode =  document.getElementById('cir');
     selectNode.style.fill="red";
```

For solving your problem , select node as a  global variable,then access as your same code.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/w2gHw/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead...

```
var selectNode =  document.getElementById('nodeId');
selectNode.style.setProperty("fill", "green", "");
```

Comment: I tried but getting this error `TypeError: selectNode.style is undefined
 

selectNode.style.setProperty("fill", "green", "");`

Comment: and using .attr instead of .style?

Comment: Same error                 :`TypeError: selectNode.attr is undefined
 

selectNode.attr.setProperty("fill", "green", "");`

Comment: What is is you want to turn green? nodeId is the input element. If it's the rect, give the rect an id and then change the getElementById to refer to that id instead.